# How to avoid View moving off the screen when keyboard appears in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui, keyboard

absolute greenhorn writing here:
i have a very basic app that does some calculations. It has only one view that has some Stacks in it that then contain text fields. underneath are two buttons and an image. when I now click on a text field, the view moves up and off the screen even though I want to make the keyboard over the buttons and image as I do not need them visible when the keyboard is active. I have tried to apply the `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)`addition to basically everything in the view but it still does it.

Screenshot with Keyboard up
[image: Screenshot with Keyboard up]

```
    VStack{
        Spacer()
        HStack (alignment: .top){
            
            VStack (alignment: .trailing, spacing:8){
                
                Text("Volumenstrom")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                Text("Geschwindigkeit")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                Text("Kanalmaß A")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                Text("Kanalmaß B")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                Text("Durchmesser D")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
            }
            
            VStack (alignment: .center){
                
                TextField("0", text: $VolumenstromEingabe,
                          onCommit : { self.BerechungVG1(); self.BerechungVG2()} )
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .modifier(ClearButton(text: $VolumenstromEingabe))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
                TextField("0", text: $GeschwindigkeitEingabe,
                          onCommit: {self.BerechungVG1(); self.BerechungVG2()})
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .modifier(ClearButton(text: $GeschwindigkeitEingabe))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
                
                TextField("0", text: $KanalAEingabe,
                          onCommit: { self.BerechungVGA()})
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .modifier(ClearButton(text: $KanalAEingabe))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
                
                TextField("0", text: $KanalBEingabe,
                          onCommit: { self.BerechungVAB(); self.BerechungVGD()
                })
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .modifier(ClearButton(text: $KanalBEingabe))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
                
                TextField("0", text: $KanalDErgebnis,
                          onCommit: { self.BerechungDg(); self.BerechungVG1()})
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .modifier(ClearButton(text: $KanalDErgebnis))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
                
            }
            
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 8){
                
                Text("in m³/h")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                Text("in m/s")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                Text("in mm")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                Text("in mm")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                Text("in mm")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            }
            
            
            
        }
        Button(action:  {
            self.ClearAll()
        
        
        })   {
            Text("Reset")}
        
        
        
        Spacer()
        
        
        HStack{
            
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Image("Logo Martin neu-60")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                    .padding()
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingInfoSheet.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Informationen")
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                    
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingInfoSheet, content: {
                    ScrollView1()
                })
                
                Text("Luftkanalrechner v1.0, Build 6")
                    .padding()
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` to the outermost VStack?

Comment: thanks for your reply! is there a way to attach it to the stack itself? I thought it could only be done to elements in the stack, at least that is what Xcode is letting me do.  it now looks like this, still everything moves up when the keyboard appears.

Comment: the top of the view now: `var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Spacer()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)`   - sorry about the mess, I am fighting with the formating still. i feel like it has something to do with the image but deleting that part of the code still didn't fix my problem.